# Determine if a point is within a region

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary, geolocation

I have a kml file that contains many regions (say buildings or properties). The shapes might be complicated (not just rectangles, but potentially n sided, or even convex), but for the most part they will be small (none more than a km a side). There are potentially tens of thousands of coordinates and hundreds (maybe thousands) of regions.

I want to know if any coordinate of a set of coordinates is inside one of these regions, and if so, what coordinate(s) and what region(s). This could be done by finding all the points within each region one region at a time, or by finding out if each point lies within a region one point at a time.

I hope for a database driven solution of some kind, but am open to any solution.

The application will be launched on a Amazon EC2 instance, so something compatible with RDS would be nice)

Tentative solution would be the ST_WITHIN or ST_CONTAINS or ST_INTERSECTS in mysql, but I am unclear about the difference between them.

I have also looked at Google Fusion Tables, and cannot find an SQL query that does what I want (doesn't mean that there isn't one - I just missed it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in using Fusion Tables to solve this problem, you can use [ST_INTERSECTS](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#spatial):

> Used in the WHERE clause. The syntax is: `ST_INTERSECTS(<location_column>, <geometry>)`
>
> For <location_column>, use a <column_name> in your table that
>   contains location data.
>
> For <geometry>, use one of the following:
>
> - <circle>
> - <rectangle>
>
> ST_INTERSECTS cannot be combined with ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE.

Unfortunately, you can't use LATLNG directly. However, [CIRCLE](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#spatial)s can be as small as 1 meter. The following should be good enough:

```
select * from <table> where st_intersects(<column>,
circle(latlng(<latitude>, <longitude>), 1))
```

Comment: I did end up using fusion tables as part of my solution, however not the part related to this question. I am also trying to move away from ft altogether because the extra latency involved in sending a secondary request to fusion tables is not desirable. I do like that this solution allows for the point to be slightly inaccurate (as is often the case with gps results).

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I ended up using geodjango with a backing mysql database.

```
RegionContainer.objects.filter(region_area__contains=Point(longitude, latitude))
```

Gives a list of regions that which contain the point with the given latitude and longitude coordinates. The python/django code becomes the sql query.

```
SELECT `locationapp_region_container`.`id`,
       `locationapp_region_container`.`profile_id`,
       AsText(`locationapp_region_container`.`region_area`) 
       FROM `locationapp_region_container` 
       WHERE MBRContains(`locationapp_region_container`.`region_area`,
       GeomFromText(POINT (80.6123000000000047 -43.2349804300000002)))
```

Because the backing database is MySQL, it is RDS supported.