# find point in inside polygon ..with mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry, geospatial

Created table like below

`CREATE TABLE` geo`(`id`int DEFAULT NULL,`geometry`text,`spatialdata `geometry DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB`

inserted data

`insert into` geo `(`id`,` geometry`,` spatialdata`) values('2','POLYGON ((-118.282067 34.067679, -118.281555 34.067458, -118.281467 34.067419, -118.280624 34.067055, -118.279672 34.066689, -118.279376 34.066558, -118.279233 34.066489, -118.279098 34.066409, -118.278879 34.066251, -118.278047 34.065631, -118.276573 34.067943, -118.276505 34.06805, -118.275848 34.069081, -118.275294 34.069984, -118.274929 34.070554, -118.273876 34.072198, -118.27485 34.072519, -118.2753 34.072711, -118.275707 34.072889, -118.276615 34.073286, -118.27752 34.073681, -118.277735 34.073343, -118.277791 34.073256, -118.278056 34.072844, -118.278522 34.072117, -118.278988 34.071389, -118.279463 34.070648, -118.280081 34.070915, -118.280249 34.070772, -118.281158 34.06934, -118.282183 34.06773, -118.282067 34.067679))',NULL);`

now i would like to check if below point have inside polygon or not

Ex   -118.282194 34.06773

I am new to stackoverflow... I have searched in stackoverflow  but not found answer.

I have tried below link

[Lon/Lat Order when using spatial POINT type with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082696/lon-lat-order-when-using-spatial-point-type-with-mysql)

[Determine if a point is within a region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467118/determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-region)

Comment: Here is an example using MySQL 8 and SRID 4326 - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pb1AsbM6). Note the coordinates are all (lat, lon) not (lon, lat) as it is using 4326.

Comment: Welcome to *Stack Overflow*! Please edit your question to share the code that you have managed to produce so far, so that the community can help you overcome the difficulties you are experiencing.